# How to test an MVC route with optional querystring parameters

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mvccontrib, attributerouting

I have this controller method:

```
[GET("/whatever/list")]
public ActionResult Index(string sortby, string order)
```

I'm trying to test it with MvcContrib route testing:

```
"~/whatever/list".ShouldMapTo<MyController>(c => c.Index(string.Empty, string.Empty));
"~/whatever/list?sortby=type&order=desc".ShouldMapTo<MyController>(c => c.Index("type", "desc"));
```

However, it returns this error.

> Failure: MvcContrib.TestHelper.AssertionException : Value for
>   parameter 'sortby' did not match: expected '' but was ''; no value
>   found in the route context action parameter named 'sortby' - does your
>   matching route contain a token called 'sortby'?

What am I missing?

Comment: I think the first tests failing:: `"~/whatever/list".ShouldMapTo<MyController>(c => c.Index(string.Empty, string.Empty));` try with `null` instead of `string.Empty` because `null` is the default value of `string`.

Comment: If you were to do that as an answer, I'd mark it answered.  That seemed to do it, I don't know why that didn't hit me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the assert message (`expected '' but was '';` so one of the values is `null` or `string.Empty` in the assertation) your first test is failing, because you used `string.Empty` but the default value for string is `null`

Change your assert to use `null` and it should wotk:

```
"~/whatever/list".ShouldMapTo<MyController>(c => c.Index(null, null));
```

Comment: What if Index's parameters were ints? Then you can't pass null, how would you make that test pass (without changing controller's method to except nullable)?

Comment: Then I guess you would need to use `0` because that's the default value of int. So your assert would look like `"~/whatever/list".ShouldMapTo<MyController>(c => c.Index(0, 0));` but I cannot be sure without seeing your controller and your routing configs

Comment: Actually this is what I tried, but the controller's action accepted int and the assertion fails because it gets null instead (which I can't pass as non nullable int) - `expected '0' but was ''`

Answer (score 2):

I used like

```
var route = "~/whatever/list".WithMethod(HttpVerbs.Get);
route.Values.Add("sortby", "type");
route.Values.Add("order", "desc");
route.ShouldMapTo<MyController>(c => c.Index("type", "desc"));
```